# How to change a logo by using a browse button

Tags: c#, wpf

My code so far will let me browse for a Image on my computer with a filter. When I browse for the image I want my image, that it set on my application to change on all my forms to the image I selected.

```
private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();



    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";


    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document 
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        txtFileLocation.Text = filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Button_Click_4` What is this, WinForms?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

Comment: what you really want to do? You selected an image using OpenFileDialog and what next? Use it as application background or what?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I want it so when i select a new logo with the browse button and click select it changes the logo that is already on the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your Logo is an image of some kind. If you change the source of the image to the path of the file/image you have selected you should be good to go. I have added a control to my xaml called MyImage which should be your logo:

```
        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));
        }
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Name="MyImage"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Or shorter: `MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));`

Comment: @Snorre Thanks for the suggestion just got back, could you give me an example of your XAML code as i cant find the <control> tag in my logo.

Comment: @Snorre Question .. How come there is a button click control on the image?